# How do I make bash find upload.php AND pass parameters?

Tags: php, bash

I have this command

```
php upload.php?qdatei=temp%2Fsession_ids%2F75hbhgedlj6i03vdifpd5save1-1.txt&edatei=temp%2Ffortschritt%2F75hbhgedlj6i03vdifpd5save1-ergebnis.txt&fdatei=temp%2Ffortschritt%2F75hbhgedlj6i03vdifpd5save1-1.txt&id=11
```

Where upload.php cannot be found in linux.

So I changed it to

```
php upload.php -- 'qdatei=temp%2Fsession_ids%2F75hbhgedlj6i03vdifpd5save1-1.txt&edatei=temp%2Ffortschritt%2F75hbhgedlj6i03vdifpd5save1-ergebnis.txt&fdatei=temp%2Ffortschritt%2F75hbhgedlj6i03vdifpd5save1-1.txt&id=11'
```

which made php find upload.php but not pass any parameters.

How do I make linux find upload.php AND pass parameters?

Comment: This only would work if your script were to evaluate `argv`. Otherwise you need the `php-cgi` binary and set up the according environment; those variables belonging in the `QUERY_STRING` for instance.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php